# Angular 16 upgrade. AppComponent elements errors out as "not a known element"

Tags: angular, upgrade

We are trying to upgrade our app to Angular 16. During the build All AppComponent HTML elements are showing as "not a known element" even though all needed modules were listed as imports in "AppModule". It appears like as if the there is no link between appModule and appComponent.

example build error

```
NG8001: 'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element
```

**main.ts has below **

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**AppModule has all needed imports with below bootstrap to Appcomponent as well**

```
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

**Note:** This is working fine when we migrated from Angular 14 -- Angular 15. We are not looking into moving the app to have "standalone" components yet.

Anyone here ran into similar issues, please provide your valuable inputs. Appreciate any responses in advance.

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Here is the files section in tsconfig.app.json

```
 "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"]
```

Comment: Could you post your `main.ts` and `app.config.ts` files? Angular v16 uses a slightly different approach for bootstrapping the application at start than previous angular versions.

Comment: added main.ts and files section from tsconfig.app.json

Comment: There is no [MRE]